# In Swift, JavaScript doesn't work for multiple function calls

Tags: javascript, swift, macos, wkwebview, javascriptcore

I am trying to execute JavaScript through Swift.  I am trying to enter text into a textbox and click a button.  However, when I try to do both, only the text entering works.  It works when I only try to do one.  Changing the order (clicking the button and then entering the text) still only enters the text, but doesn't click the button.  In addition, if I manually enter text into the box, the JavaScript won't change the text, but it will click the button.  Here is the JavaScript:

```
function grabID (parent, child)
{
parent = document.getElementById(parent);
var descendants = parent.getElementsByTagName(child);
if ( descendants.length )
  return descendants[0];
   return null;
}
grabID("search-form", "input").value = "test";

grabID("search-form", "button").click();
```

I use the function grabID to reference the search bar and button because they don't have an ID.  When I put this exact code into the JavaScript console on Chrome, it works perfectly without any issues.  I have tried multiple different ways of calling this, first putting the JavaScript all into one `EvaluateJavaScript`, then I broke it up into multiple calls of `EvaluateJavaScript`.  All of this returned the same odd result.  I am currently trying:

```
if let jsSourcePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "scripted", ofType: "js") {
        do {
            let jsSourceContents = try String(contentsOfFile: jsSourcePath)
            self.webby.evaluateJavaScript(jsSourceContents)
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Scripted.js is the file where the JavaScript is and webby is the Web View.  For testing purposes, this is in a function that is called when a button is clicked in the app.  How could I change this so it always changes the text (even if there is already text in the search bar) and always clicks the button?  Thanks.

Comment: In what life cycle of Web View do you inject the JS code?

Comment: @RikeshSubedi I don't know what you mean by life cycle, but for testing it is triggered by a button, which I manually press when the page is loaded.

Comment: what I meant was, there is a delegate method for UIWebView which is invoked when DOM is ready, it's webViewDidFinishLoad(_:). You will get access to DOM elements only after this method is invoked. Try executing the JS Script inside this method. @ben-a